# AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet works with _Templateparameterfile but not with -Templateparameteruri

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, azure-rm-template

When I deploy with ARM template with both template and parameter file in local folder, it works with no issues. But, same file if in blob container, it prompts me for all parameters. Quite strange and confused. :(

This structure works!

> Parameter Set: Deployment via template file and template parameters file
>
> > New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName  -TemplateFile >> -TemplateParameterFile  [-Force] [-Mode  >>{Incremental | Complete} ] [-Name  ] [-StorageAccountName  ] [->>TemplateVersion  ] [ ]

My above trial is as below and it works:

```
$TemplateFile =        "F:\servicerequestsnippets\FW__Code\Orig\Orig\trial\azuredeploy.json"
$TemplateParameterFile = "F:\servicerequestsnippets\FW__Code\Orig\Orig\trial\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
```

.
.
.

```
                   Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                                        -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                                        -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParameterFile `
                                                        -Verbose
```

But, Parameter file uri approach as below do not work. :(

```
$TemplateFile =   "F:\servicerequestsnippets\FW__Code\Orig\Orig\trial\azuredeploy.json"
$TemplateParametersFile = "https://hbala.blob.core.windows.net/test-container/"
```

.
.

```
{ 
foreach ($blob in $blobs) 
                { 

                   $TemplateParameterFileLink = $TemplateParametersFile + $blob.Name
                   write-host $TemplateParameterFileLink
                   Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                                        -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                                        -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParameterFileLink `
                                                        -Verbose

                }
        }
```

Note:

a. I even tried TemplateParameterUri but got same Debugmessage as:

```
cmdlet Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
**administratorLogin:** << *
```

> it is not saying of conflict , and paramfromTemplate.

- It would great to get some pointers or what you feel I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

H Bala

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the Container 'Access' set to 'Private' is the problem. I changed it to 'Public container' and it appears working! Let me confirm. But, if so, how to set proper access permission to private containers from the script?

Comment: From Azure MSDN, it appears the templates needs to be on Public Container to use parameterlink. Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dn790564.aspx#parameterslink

Comment: But, this brings a new challenge: the template skips the parameter template file entirely and throws the first parameter occurence in declaration to have missed value settings. I changed the notified parameter definition order, and next run got me the following parameter definition to have missed value input.. strange, the parameter file got all values proper and works fine if run local.